# php script not working on NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

i am working on new server NGINX and facing some problem with one of php script here is the script

```
$src = $_GET['src'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

//watermark.png will go in root dir watermark.php?src=test.jpg watermark.png w_test.php
if (eregi("200x290", $src)) {
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('empty.png');
} else {
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('no_image.png');
}
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
if(eregi('.gif',$src)) {
$image = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}
elseif(eregi('.jpeg',$src)||eregi('.jpg',$src)) {
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
elseif(eregi('.png',$src)) {
$image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
else {
exit("Your image is not a gif, jpeg or png image. Sorry.");
}
$size = getimagesize($src);
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 20;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 0;
imagecolortransparent($watermark,imagecolorat($watermark,0,0));
imagecopyresampled($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);

imagejpeg($image, "", 95);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

its a simple watermark script ... its working on Apache server buut not working on NGINX can any one help (Apache giving output but NGINX no result)
NGINX Conf ....

```
server {
    server_name xxxx.com www.xxxx.com xxxx.info www.xxxx.info;
    listen xx.xxx.xx.xx;
    root /home/xxxx/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/xxxx.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/xxxx.com_error_log;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/xxxx/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/xxxx/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9001;
    }
    #setting error pages

     error_page    404 = /xxxx.php;

     fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

     location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|htm)$ {
     expires 1y;
     log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it works on one web server and not another, the problem isn't with your code.  Check your PHP configuration, and actually dig into the error logs.  The web server doesn't know or care about PHP.  It only knows to execute PHP itself.

Comment: @Leigh nginx config added after edit please check

Comment: I think the issue may be your `try_files` inside your php location. I've had issues with it myself when using `=404`. Also quite strange that you've set all your fastcgi params outside of the location block.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be that you are not matching your location correctly.  This is what I am using.

```
index index.php;
location ~ \.php$ {
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_cache_valid   200 302  1h;
  fastcgi_cache_valid   301      1d;
  fastcgi_cache_valid   any      1m;
  fastcgi_cache_min_uses  1;
  fastcgi_cache_use_stale error  timeout invalid_header http_500;
}
```

Comment: You realise your `.*.` means any character 0 or more times, followed by any character. You want `\.php$` to be literally ending with "dot php"